# Bug between asfreq and resample in pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to understand the difference between resample and asfreq but I can't sem to wrap my head around it, in the example below I took the same dataframe and used resample and asfreq but when I count the values I get different results, how is this possible?

```
df = pd.concat([tt.asfreq('B').count(), tt.resample('B').count()], axis=1, keys = ['asfreq(B)', 'resample(B)'])
df['Diff'] = df['asfreq(B)'] - df['resample(B)']

df

    asfreq(B)   resample(B) Diff
AXP 39          47          -8
BA  81          84          -3
CVX 47          60          -13
KO  74          82          -8
DD  77          79          -2
```